# Dynamic localized WPF application with resource files

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

Trying to make my wpf appliaction localized, I followed [this CodeProject tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies).

I created my localized resource files (e.g., Resource.resx, Resource.en-US.resx) and bind these on a label element in the xaml

```
<Label Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForgroundColor}" FontSize="21"
           Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.title}"/>
```

In a LocalizedService I set the `CultureInfo` on some change events

```
class LocalizationService
{
    public static void SetLanguage(string locale)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale)) locale = "en-US";
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(locale);
    }
}
```

This solution compiles and shows the correct resource value, but because of the static binding, I could not change the locale on runtime.
When I change the content binding to a `DynamicResource` as follow shown there is no resource value shown.

```
Content="{DynamicResource strings:Resources.title}"
```

How could I bind text values to a localized resource file and change it dynamically on runtime?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an other approach of [Code Infinity here](https://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach) which also used a wrapper for dynamically binding on resource files. 
Here the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event informs your ui elements of a new binded resource file when the locale was changed.

You start to implement a BindingExtenstion:

```
public class LocalizationExtension : Binding
{
    public LocalizationExtension(string name) : base("[" + name + "]")
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        this.Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
    }
}
```

Then you need to implement the connection between a `ResourceManager` and the `CultureInfo` which is implemented as a singleton to enable synchronized access. It defines the Source for the binded element and also fires the INotifyPropertyChanged` event on localization changes:

```
public class TranslationSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly TranslationSource instance = new TranslationSource();

    public static TranslationSource Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private readonly ResourceManager resManager = Resources.Strings.Resources.ResourceManager;
    private CultureInfo currentCulture = null;

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return this.resManager.GetString(key, this.currentCulture); }
    }

    public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get { return this.currentCulture; }
        set
        {
            if (this.currentCulture != value)
            {
                this.currentCulture = value;
                var @event = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (@event != null)
                {
                    @event.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Note that your localized resource files (e.g., Resource.resx, Resource.en-US.resx) are in the folder `<Project>/Resources/Strings/Resources/` otherwise you need to update this part of the code.

Now you can use this new binding:

```
<Label Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForgroundColor}" FontSize="21"
       Content="{util:Localization title}"/>
```

To change the locale in runtime you need to set:

```
public static void SetLanguage(string locale)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale)) locale = "en-US";
    TranslationSource.Instance.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(locale);
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me. Thanks a lot! There are any way to translate in design mode too?

Comment: how to/which namespace need to add in xaml. please provide

Comment: The `LocalizationExtension` is implemented in the `MyTool.Util` namespace, so the coresponding xaml ns expression looks like: `xmlns:util="clr-namespace:MyTool.Util"`.

Comment: Thanks DTeuchert,It's working fine with only single language. 
but i am trying to change laguage on button click ist not working
here is the code:
//doubt is it corect path for Resource manager
private readonly ResourceManager resManager = WPFLocalizationNew.Resources.hi_IN.ResourceManager;
private CultureInfo currentCulture = null;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TranslationSource.Instance.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN");
}
Unfortunatly it's not working anything that i missing here? Please suggest

Comment: Resources is not updating on change please help

Comment: In the btn onclick event you only need to call the `SetLanguage("en-IN")`. Here it is important to avoid typos, therefore I defined a default language code (`"en-US"`). Please check that your Ressource file is named: "Resources.en-IN.resx"

Comment: Yes, by changing the Resources file name as Resources.en-IN/ it's perfectly working...Thank you so much

Comment: how would I get value from resource in code behind file. plz suggest

Comment: @user2675991 : What I do is storing the translation keys in an `enum`. Then I can pass the enum value to the `LocalizationExtension` with `{x:Static Keys.title}`.